# InStr to extract all text before "[" if some cells contain "[" and some do not

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following piece of code that returns a

> Run-time error '5'

as soon as it comes across a cell that do not contain **[**

```vb
Cells(i + 2, 11) = Left(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), "[") - 1)
```

In this example:
`Cheese[1]` is ok and returns `Cheese`.
`Marmite(2)[13]` is ok and returns `Marmite(2)`.
`Spreadable butter(13)` doesn't work.

What is the fix please

---

Thank you, so following on from the help below how do I incorporate and apply two `IF` statements into the following?

```vb
For i = 1 To 4
   If Cells(i * 2 + 2, 14) <> "" Then
      Cells(i + 2, 3) = Left(Right(GetURL(Cells(i * 2 + 2, 17)), 12), 7)
      Cells(i + 2, 11) = Left(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), "[") - 1)
      Cells(i + 2, 12) = Left(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 13), InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 13), "[") - 1)
   End If
Next i
```

I am only a beginner at VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check to see if it contains a **[** first...

The `Instr()` function returns a 0 if the string you are looking for cannot be found, so without an `If` statement to check for that first, you end up with a 0, and your code is subtracting 1 from the zero to get -1, and that is not a valid argument for the `Left` function, so you get the error.

```
If InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), "[") > -1 Then
  Cells(i + 2, 11) = Left(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), "[") - 1)
End If
```

This assumes the cell will never actually start with a **[**

To avoid getting an error if it IS the first character:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), "[") > 0 Then
  Cells(i + 2, 11) = Left(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), "[") - 1)
End If
```

Comment: Where do I introduce that If statement into the following then please?                                   
For i = 1 To 5
If Cells(i * 2 + 2, 5) <> "" Then
Cells(i + 2, 3) = Left(Right(GetURL(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 17)), 12), 7)
Cells(i + 2, 11) = Left(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 12), "[") - 1)
Cells(i + 2, 12) = Left(Cells(i * 2 + 1, 13), InStr(1, Cells(i * 2 + 1, 13), "[") - 1)
End If
Next i

Comment: Please do not post code that long into comments. As you can see it just turns into a mess. Instead, update (add to) your question.

Comment: But all i did was add a line before it, and a line after it, so that's all you need to do. I didnt change the line of code in question at all.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise that I should update the question rather than write it as a comment

Comment: It's ok, now you know. Also note that if this does indeed solve your issue, make sure to mark it as accepted/closed by checking the little green checkmark on the left side of where my answer starts.